# How to detect if an object is on a ray, given BoundedBox and two sets of Vector3's

Tags: c#

http://privatepaste.com/10a76dbf8f/gasfgfsdadfgdfafds

Here is my current code.  The iteration # only goes to 5.  The castSpell function never turns to false.  I would like to know what is wrong with my code.  Thanks!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You must define size for your array, and init them. Should be something like this

```
SpellDataInst[] spells = new SpellDataInst[5];

// init each of the index inside the array
for (int i = 0; i < spells.length; i++)
{
     spells[i] = new ObjectManager.Player.Spellbook.Spells;
}
```

Comment: Oh no, I mean I want the iteration to go higher than 5, to something like 50 or so... it just doesn't seem to iterate past 5 for some reason.

Comment: then you should set your while condition to (x < 50)